# Can we access a webservice developed using c# using java client without crossdomain.xml file

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Hi 
Can we access a c# webservice using java client , even if there is no crossdomain.xml file present on for eg, IIS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as this web service is exposed over some interoperable protocol such as SOAP you can access it from a Java client without any problems and need of `crossdomain.xml`.

Comment: then whats the use of crossdomain.xml ? or is it needed only for javascript clients ?

Comment: This file could be used by Silverlight or Adobe Flash clients.